# Extract value from read only form selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

This was the html element

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c64-9"><!----><input _ngcontent-acc-c94="" matinput="" readonly="true" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-star-inserted" style="display: none;" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false"><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-acc-c94="" class="ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-acc-c94="" class="ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-acc-c94="" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="mailto:as.sda@abc.com">as.sda@abc.com</a></span><!----><!----></span><!----><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c64-9"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c64-9 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-1" for="mat-input-0" aria-owns="mat-input-0"><!----><mat-label _ngcontent-acc-c94="" class="ng-tns-c64-9 ng-star-inserted">E-mail</mat-label><!----><!----></label><!----></span></div>
```

My code:

```
owner_id=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'')
owner_id=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'')
```

I have tried extracting using xpath,css selector,classsname and nothing worked. Please help me out incase you guys know

Comment: Which element value are you trying to fetch?

Comment: I am trying to fetch the text(email) inside the <a> tag  @KunduK

Comment: Please checkout my solution, if that works for you?

Comment: didn't work got a timeoutexception @KunduK

Comment: Also if I run that without EC wait I get InvalidArgumentException error @KunduK

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be `visible` and following `xpath`.

```
owner_id=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(., 'E-mail')]/preceding-sibling::span[1]//a")))
print(owner_id.text)
print(owner_id.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Import below libarries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I tried this got a timeout exception @KunduK

Comment: Also if I run that without EC wait I get InvalidArgumentException error @KunduK

Comment: @qcoder: can you please post the url, if it is public? based on the `html` I have provided solution.

Comment: Its not public thats why I couldnt post the url. But that html is from a readonly form

Comment: Try this : `owner_id=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(., 'E-mail')]/preceding-sibling::span[1]//a")))`

Comment: change from `visibility_of_element_located` to `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: okay if its difficukt for u can you try to get the value from thsi readonly form in this url

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_readonly

Comment: Tried still didnt work @KunduK

Comment: I think its not about EC wait. Its more about it being readonly

Comment: That is `input` field. If you use this code it will work `print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#country"))).get_attribute("value"))`

Comment: I tried and got timeout exception error @KunduK

Comment: Did the code work in ur sysytem?

Comment: @qcoder : Yes, it is coming Norway.

Comment: How come same code didnt work for me @KunduK

Comment: @qcoder : I wonder, something must have wrong at your end.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the Html source you posted, I can get the email id using the below code:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mat-form-field-infix.ng-tns-c64-9 span a").text)
```

Output:

```
as.sda@abc.com
```

Comment: no such element exception error